# Get the last day of a year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas df with a year column. I want to get the last day of that year.
For example: 2020 --> 2020/12/31

I tried:

```
data['Date']=datetime.date(year=data['Year'].astype(int), month=12, day=31)
```

but I get this error: "cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> "

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

PS I realized I could just do:

```
data['Date']=data['Year']+"/12/31"
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
```

but I'm still wondering what was wrong in my previous code

Comment: `datetime.date` doesn't know how to work with a dataframe. The `astype` method doesn't actually return an `int`, it returns an entire column whose elements are `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Datetime.date` works with single entries one at a time. When using `data['year'].astype(int)` you're trying to pass an Series as an argument and not a single value (as it's expected).
For that to work, it'd be something like

```
data['Date']= data['Year'].apply(lambda x:datetime.date(year=x, month=12, day=31))
```

But it's somewhat inefficient, the second way you suggested would be faster.

Comment: `.map` is intended to use i those cases instead of `.apply` where you might have to specify the axis. You also forgot a bracket at the end.